# Issue when rendering in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders

Recently followed a tutorial in blender: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5naMFeWTBeY&ab_channel=Iridesium
Which is about making black holes in blender using Volumetrics and noise textures for the side ring and layer weight for the inner hole in Cycles.
However, when rendering, there is no colour, and the texture is messed up

Heres how it looks while viewing, and the other is the rendered proudct

[image: How it should look]

[image: How its coming out]

I have no idea what is causing this problem

Comment: You should not leave any link as it is , you should always explain what does that tutorial contain so that this community can help you better with your problem

Comment: Ah, sorry, will fix

Comment: did it already for you

Comment: Thank you very much, still very new to all this

Comment: No problem dude , just chill and continue doing this , PS : not being rude with that comment , it really creates a problem , half the people will not bother watching the video and u'll end up getting late awnsere...so always tell whats the content

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!

I had apparently left a sun light source within the project, having hidden it and not deleted it. After having deleted it, the render came out perfectly.